# DOM elements attached to the window object via their ID -- expected behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

I just stumbled over a weird issue (a combination of Stack Overflow JavaScript and a user script someone was running) that I could trace back to the fact that the user script was was accessing a variable that no longer existed (because we made some changes in the SO JS).

But instead of being `undefined` / throwing errors, this variable was actually returning a DOM element, which happened to have the variable's name as its element ID.

I was sure this was a Chrome bug and was just about to file a report, so I tested other browsers, only to notice they exhibit similar – but not identical – behavior.

### Test case:

```
<body id="a-b-c">
<div id="something"></div>
something has type <script>document.write(typeof something)</script><br>
window["a-b-c"] has type
    <script>document.write(typeof window["a-b-c"])</script><br>
window.hasOwnProperty("something") is
    <script>document.write(window.hasOwnProperty("something"))</script><br>
something === document.getElementById("something") is
    <script>document.write(something === document.getElementById("something"))</script><br>
</body>
```

### Outputs:

#### Firefox:

> something has type object
> window["a-b-c"] has type undefined
> window.hasOwnProperty("something") is true
> something === document.getElementById("something") is true

#### IE8:

> something has type object
> window["a-b-c"] has type object
> window.hasOwnProperty("something") is
> something === document.getElementById("something") is true

#### Chrome:

> something has type object
> window["a-b-c"] has type object
> window.hasOwnProperty("something") is false
> something === document.getElementById("something") is true

#### Safari/Opera:

> something has type object
> window["a-b-c"] has type object
> window.hasOwnProperty("something") is true
> something === document.getElementById("something") is true

So my question:

- Is this behavior defined anywhere?
- If so, which of the browsers is doing it right?
- Is there a situation where this is actually helpful? I can only come up with problems this *creates*, but really none that it *solves*.

Comment: bobince has provided a good analysis of this issue when answering this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here

Comment: Very strange... why should window.something exist at all? Is the user script adding a property to the window object when the DOM element is created?

Comment: meouw's comment should be reposted as an answer :)

Comment: Weird ... http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Qu5zv/

Comment: @ithcy: No, the user script was trying to access a variable that previously existed (put into the global namespace by the SO JavaScript). Since I removed that variable today, the user script instead received the dom element with that id.